# How do I set-up and access a config JSON file with secret information for a public GitHub repo?

Tags: javascript, json, git, github, configuration

I am building a website and am using Git and a public repo on GitHub for version control. I want to keep my secret information out of the public repo but my source code still needs to access it. Conceptually I believe I have researched the answer but I am missing the actual steps to do this. Any help/guidance appreciated.

### Research

Based mainly on these excellent posts - [this](https://rosspenman.com/api-key-exposure), [this](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3064355/security/how-you-might-be-leaking-your-secrets-onto-github.html) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control) - here's what I've found so far:

- Don't hard code secret info eg passwords into source code
- Use a config file to store secret information
- Make sure the config file is in `.gitignore` so it is not pushed to GitHub
- The config file can be JSON or YAML. As I'm using Javascript in my code I'm opting for JSON
- Be careful where the config file is saved on the server

### Code

In my `config.json` file I include my secret information:

```
{
    "APItoken": "tokenPassword",
    "secretToken": "passwordToken"
}
```

Then in my HTML file I add a `script` to access the relevant information from the `config.json` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.json"></script>

var mySecretData = JSON.parse(config);
password = mySecretData[0];
token = mySecretData[1];
```

Would really appreciate help if I'm going in the right direction and if I need to make any changes to my code?

And finally, what does the point mean about where I save `config.json` file on the server mean?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see missing is that you will need a server-side process to consume the config file. By the looks of your posted html/js, you're doing this client side.

```
src="config.json"
```

This means it's publicly available to the world. You need to store the config outside the web directory somewhere else on the file system where only your server-side application code may reach it.

It's not clear what are you trying to achieve in your script specifically, because I don't really see any reason why you would want to send database credentials to the client from your posted code.

You should be using node or some server side language to source the config, connect to the database, and then broker the data between the client. Your other conclusions about ignoring from source code are right on track.

Comment: Btw, I +1'd your reply but it won't show until my reputation score is higher.

Comment: my `dbPassword` example is completely misleading. I will edit so it is clearer that I have looking at primarily API tokens, and also Google Analytics key. Would I still need to store the config file server-side if I need it for API tokens to be used client-side?